# To check the convergence of an optimization solver “ipopt” using CheckConvergence() function

Tags: python, optimization, ipopt

I am using ipopt solver for a non-linear optimization problem in Python. The ipopt documentation states a function CheckConvergence() by which the convergence status of the solution can be obtained.

https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/classIpopt_1_1ConvergenceCheck.html

I tried to access the function with steps below:

```
solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')
solver.solve(model)
solver.CheckConvergence()
```

But I got an error, AttributeError: 'IPOPT' object has no attribute 'CheckConvergence'.

So I am trying to import the script from file IpConvCheck.hpp where this function is defined.

https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/IpConvCheck_8hpp_source.html

I would appreciate it if someone can help me to solve this.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned `CheckConvergence()` function is a method in the `Ipopt::ConvergenceCheck` class of Ipopt. Maybe it is accessible via Ipopts C++ API, but you seem to use some sort of Python interface to Ipopt.
I would suggest checking with the creators of that Python interface.

But first you might want to reconsider what you try to achieve by calling this function. After Ipopt finished solving, it returns a status code that indicates why Ipopt stopped and there are statistics available to get the primal and dual violations (if a solution is returned). You probably want to inspect these (assuming that they are available with the Python interface) and not call some Ipopt-internal function that is used to check whether Ipopt is terminating at the current iterate.